# How can I make inference for an Vertex AutoML tabular model for classification?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I've trained an Vertex AutoML tabular model for classification and I want to made an inference for this model with my custom code which is using the python tensorflow library

Here's my code

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import struct2tensor.ops.gen_decode_proto_sparse

# load models
model = tf.saved_model.load(export_dir='/projects/zhenwei/Vertex_AutoML_Test/model/predict/001', )


# get signatures
infer = model.signatures["serving_default"]

# make inputs
string_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(tf.constant(["7","0.27","0.36","20.7","0.045","45","170","1.001","3","0.45","8.9"]), dtype=tf.string)
inputs = {"inputs": string_tensor}

# inference
result = infer(**inputs)
```

But I got this error

```
2023-11-17 08:05:51.537499: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:936] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2023-11-17 08:05:51.546405: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:936] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2023-11-17 08:05:51.548095: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:936] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2023-11-17 08:05:51.549929: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 AVX512F FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-11-17 08:05:51.559053: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:936] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2023-11-17 08:05:51.560776: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:936] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2023-11-17 08:05:51.562428: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:936] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2023-11-17 08:05:52.430231: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:936] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2023-11-17 08:05:52.432202: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:936] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2023-11-17 08:05:52.433899: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:936] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2023-11-17 08:05:52.435578: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1525] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 561 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: Tesla T4, pci bus id: 0000:00:05.0, compute capability: 7.5
2023-11-17 08:06:00.982148: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1745] OP_REQUIRES failed at decode_proto_sparse_op.cc:940 : DATA_LOSS: Failed skipping unrequested field
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "predict.py", line 42, in <module>
    result = infer(**inputs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1601, in __call__
    return self._call_impl(args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/wrap_function.py", line 243, in _call_impl
    return super(WrappedFunction, self)._call_impl(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1619, in _call_impl
    return self._call_with_flat_signature(args, kwargs, cancellation_manager)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1668, in _call_with_flat_signature
    return self._call_flat(args, self.captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1853, in _call_flat
    return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 499, in call
    outputs = execute.execute(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 54, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.DataLossError: Graph execution error:

2 root error(s) found.
  (0) DATA_LOSS:  Failed skipping unrequested field
         [[{{node DecodeProtoSparseV4}}]]
         [[PartitionedCall/DecodeProtoMapV2/_22]]
  (1) DATA_LOSS:  Failed skipping unrequested field
         [[{{node DecodeProtoSparseV4}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_pruned_22584]
```

I can make sure that my local environment meets the requirements written in the path(model/environment.json)

```json
{"container_uri": "us-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/automl-tabular/prediction-server:20231009_1325", "tensorflow": "2.8.0", "struct2tensor": "0.39.0", "tensorflow-addons": "0.16.1"}
```

I checked the official documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/export/export-model-tabular#before-you-begin). But I don't want to use docker image to make the prediction. Since it's a tensorflow model, can you help to check why this error happened?

I want to make inference with my custom code.

Here's the structure of the csv file, 11 feature columns and 1 target column

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lRVw.png)